# Error in Apache Beam Read from BQ and Publish to PubSub in Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

My task is to read from a BigQuery table and publish the results as a PubSub message.
I came up with the below code, but getting error.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/pubsubio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/log"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/options/gcpopts"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/x/beamx"
)

// CommentRow models 1 row of HackerNews comments.
type CommentRow struct {
    Text string `bigquery:"text"`
}

func init() {
    beam.RegisterFunction(typeConvert)
}

const query = `SELECT text
FROM ` + "`bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`" + `
WHERE time_ts BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' and text IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1000
`

func typeConvert(list CommentRow) []byte {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(list)
    return b
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    beam.Init()

    ctx := context.Background()
    p := beam.NewPipeline()
    s := p.Root()
    project := gcpopts.GetProject(ctx)

    // Build a PCollection<CommentRow> by querying BigQuery.
    rows := bigqueryio.Query(s, project, query,
        reflect.TypeOf(CommentRow{}), bigqueryio.UseStandardSQL())

    pc := beam.ParDo(s, func(row CommentRow, emit func(CommentRow)) {
        emit(row)
    }, rows)

    pc1 := beam.ParDo(s, typeConvert, pc)

    pubsubio.Write(s, project, "projects/PROJECTID/topics/test-topic", pc1)

    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, p); err != nil {
        log.Exitf(ctx, "Failed to execute job: %v", err)
    }
}
```

I submit it as a Dataflow job with the parameters like below

```
go run main.go --project=PROJECTID --runner=dataflow --region=us-east1 --staging_location=gs://PROJECTID/tmp
```

The dataflow job is getting failed with the below message in the logs.

```
Workflow failed. Causes: S01:bigquery.Query/Impulse+bigquery.Query/bigqueryio.queryFn+main.main.func1+main.typeConvert+pubsubio.Write/pubsubio.wrapInMessage+pubsubio.Write/pubsubio.marshalMessageFn+pubsubio.Write/External failed., The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures. If the logs only contain generic timeout errors related to accessing external resources, such as MongoDB, verify that the worker service account has permission to access the resource's subnetwork. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work item was attempted on these workers: 

  go-job-1-1675656194525980-02052003-s9sp-harness-189k
      Root cause: Could not find the sink for pubsub, Check that the sink library specifies alwayslink = 1.,

  go-job-1-1675656194525980-02052003-s9sp-harness-189k
      Root cause: Could not find the sink for pubsub, Check that the sink library specifies alwayslink = 1.,

  go-job-1-1675656194525980-02052003-s9sp-harness-189k
      Root cause: Could not find the sink for pubsub, Check that the sink library specifies alwayslink = 1.,

  go-job-1-1675656194525980-02052003-s9sp-harness-189k
      Root cause: Could not find the sink for pubsub, Check that the sink library specifies alwayslink = 1.
```

I tried searching for the error and found a similar issue faced a few years back. But no solution on library from apache-beam go sdk was provided. Wondering if there is a solution which someone can provide now?
I'm able to do something similar using the Python SDK but struggling to go past this step in Go.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi @Ashok KS, can you try the solution provided in this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651665/go-apache-beam-gcp-dataflow-could-not-find-the-sink-for-pubsub-check-that-th)? Let me know if that helps.